# i want Scrollbar in search input field

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Hi i am a beginner i want to add a scroll bar in my input field of search box .
using this code

```
.ex1{
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

<div class=ex1> .... </div>
```

using this code i achieve scroll bar but the list of search doesn't comes down .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPvTC.png)

i want my scroll bar and search data comes like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyABp.png)

please help me in code.

Comment: this is done via javascript and injected markup

Comment: please, show the html code used to the searchbox , it will be easier to help you

Comment: can you read it from inspect element ? i have lived it too , please have a look a top of page search box (https://chase.pk/)

Comment: @fcalderan how can i do this please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give height for div tag it  is possible to scroll

```
.ex1{
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
<div class="ex1" style="height:300px"> .... </div>
```

Comment: please have a look a top of page search box (chase.pk)

Comment: bro that height trick makes 300 px  div please check online on my site from inspect element

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you should have different divs, one for input field and other to show result so that you can add scroll in the second div only.

Give the second div `position:absolute` to place it and use `max-height` to give it the maximum height and then add `overflow-y:auto` to add scroll when it's needed otherwise it'll be in hidden form.

Comment: please test in inspect element bro (chase.pk) and let me know